# Mysql does not download properly because of rvm

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rvm

I originally configured my computer with rails, ruby and rvm.  Afterwards, I downloaded mysql, but when I typed in mysql --version, it tells me that it is not installed.  My echo path shows

```
/Users/ming/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@default/bin:/Users/ming/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/Users/ming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/ming/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I am not sure if it's because I have both .bash_profile (blank) and .profile (export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH").  I know that if they both exist, the latter would be ignored and since my .bash_profile is blank, mysql was saved to la-la land.  When I copied the export PATH to the .bash_profile, I get an error message that reads:

"[[ -s "/Users/ming/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/ming/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session."

I am using: 
Snow Leopard
Rails 3
Ruby 1.9.2
RVM

While I love RVM, it's becoming a real hassle so far whenever I download something new.

I read a bunch of stuff about this and it hasn't been helpful.  Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you install MySQL? Source, binary package, macports, homebrew?

Comment: I installed through the dev.mysql.com site using the dmg package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you installed MySQL (there are a dozen ways to do so)

- from source
- from binary dmg
- from macports
- from fink
- from brew

My recommandations is to install MySQL through the 'brew' command.
Personally I use .bash_profile along with rvm/brew and so far no issues.

I can't see the MySQL path in your $PATH though and neither the error message.

Try adding this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
```

to your favourite file.

Comment: I downloaded the dmg file from the dev.mysql.com site.

Comment: what do you mean by "my favorite file"?

Comment: .bash_profile or .profile, whatever you are using. I use .bash_profile

Comment: Thanks.  My comp was going crazy for a while but I finally got it.  I added this to the .bash_profile = /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin.